# Creating a JSON out of a .txt file using Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

This is what the data looks like in the txt file (tab delimited):

```
President, U.S. Vote For 1  0 of 1,599 precincts reporting
Candidate   Party   Votes
Deval Patrick   DEM 0
Bernie Sanders  DEM 0
Joseph R. Biden DEM 0
Michael R. Bloomberg    DEM 0
Elizabeth Warren    DEM 0
Pete Buttigieg  DEM 0
Tom Steyer  DEM 0
Andrew Yang DEM 0
Michael Bennet  DEM 0
John K. Delaney DEM 0
Tulsi Gabbard   DEM 0
Cory Booker DEM 0
```

This is the schema for the JSON I want to create:

```
"races": [ {   
        "name": "President, U.S.",
        "reference_id": "US-President",
        "election_date": "2020-03-17",
        "market": "balt",
        "state_postal": "MD",
        "reporting_units": [
            {
                "name": "US",
                "level": "fed",
                "state_postal": "MD",
                "precincts_reporting": 0,
                "total_precincts": 1599,
                "data_source_update_time": "2020-02-25T19:54:23+0000",
                "candidates": [
                    {
                        "last_name": "Patrick",
                        "middle_name":null,
                        "first_name":"Deval",  
                        "party": "DEM",
                        "vote_count": 0,
                    }, ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

So the `candidates` object would have to exist for each candidate, and there are many more `races` that are included in the txt file. I know I'd use `json.dumps` for this but I'm really struggling with the syntax of how to address each row of this text file.

Comment: Please give a [mre] to show the specific problem with your attempt to implement this.

Comment: Start by not worrying about the JSON part of the problem. You first goal is to just create a structure of regular Python lists and dictionaries the way you want it. You can use the `csv` module in the standard library to parse the file (just set the delimiter to `"\t"` for tab separators) line by line.

Comment: It's difficult to match up a lot of the keys and lists in the JSON example with the example input data. Probably if you (really) simplify the schema to have the parts you're having trouble with, and make sure the example of input data is something that could populate it... And some code showing what you tried might be good too.. just try not to overload us with too much info.

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour; pay attention to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow is not a coding or tutorial resource; "struggling with the syntax" is not a *specific* problem we can solve for you, as you've posted no attempt to solve this.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

If your source file is regular, you may want to consider parsing the file line-by-line to read it into python:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
    # Loop through each line;
    # Separate logic for parsing 1st line and subsequent lines, 
    # along with any other cases you have to consider
```